# Conditional statement inside EventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to calculate bmi and after doing that have a button appear that provides more information on the calculation result. When the 'what does this mean' button is clicked, info should pop up based on the bmi score calculated.

```js
const generatebutton = document.getElementById("explainbutton");


const wt = document.getElementById("b2");
const ht = document.getElementById("b3");
const bmi = document.getElementById("b5");
const calc = document.getElementById("b7");
const clr = document.getElementById("b8");

// // calculate bmi funtion
function calculate() {
  const wt = document.getElementById("b2").value;
  const ht = document.getElementById("b3").value;
  const solve = Number.parseFloat(wt / ht ** 2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("b5").textContent = solve;
};

// function make explain button appear 

function genbutton() {
  generatebutton.style.visibility = "visible";
};


calc.addEventListener("click", function() {
  calculate();
  genbutton();
});

clr.addEventListener("click", function() {
  wt.value = "";
  ht.value = "";
  bmi.textContent = "";
});


//set variables for explanation
const explain = document.getElementById("explain")

const under = document.getElementById("under")

const healthy = document.getElementById("healthy")

const over = document.getElementById("over")

const obese = document.getElementById("obese")

//pop up text
var btn = document.getElementById("explainbutton");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const bmi = document.getElementById("b5");
  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    explain.classList.toggle("open-under")
  } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
    explain.classList.toggle("open-healthy")
  } else if (bmi > 24.9 && bmi < 29.9) {
    explain.classList.toggle("open-overweight")
  } else {
    explain.classList.toggle("open-obese")
  }
});
```

```css
#explainbutton {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 190px;
}


/* pop-up explanation options */

.box {
  background: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-under .under {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-healthy .healthy {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-over .over {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-obese .obese {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


/*  */
```

```html
<div id="b1">
  <span id="sp1">
    WEIGHT(kg) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b2">
  </input>
</div>
<br>
<div id="b9">
  <span id="sp2">
    HEIGHT(m) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b3">
  </input>
</div>
<br>

<div id="bmibox">
  BMI :
  <span id="b5"> </span>
  <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="What does this mean?" class="styled-button-2" id="explainbutton" />
  <div class="box" id="explain">
    <span class="under" , id="under">You are in the underweight range</span>
    <span class="healthy" id="healthy"> You are in the healthy range </span>
    <span class="over" id="over"> You are in the overweight range </span>
    <span class="obese" id="obese"> You are in the obese range</span>
  </div>


</div>

<br>
<br>
<div id="b6">
  <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calculate" class="styled-button-2" id="b7" />
  <button id="b8">Clear</button>
</div>
```

The basic pop-up function works fine without the condition.

So I'm not sure what is stopping the script from running. I've also tried making the conditional a function in a separate block before adding it back into the EventListener.

Comment: There is no need to close an `<input>` with `</input>`; the browser completely ignores it.

Comment: `document.getElementById("b5")` returns an element - did you want its value instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX oh - yes, I wanted the value

Comment: Just a small mistake,you get the element but not the value   btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const bmi = document.getElementById("b5").innerText;

Comment: you may want `const bmi = +document.getElementById("b5").textContent;` -also you have a bug with `"open-overweight"` since you have no `overweight` just `over` - and exactly `24.9` will result in `obese` for obvious reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did, is the variable `bmi` you put in the event listener gets the whole text, not just the number. So what I did was put `parseFloat()` and put the text inside. That detects the number it sees and changes the variable to a number. Next I put a text variable so If you want to do it a second time it hides the old text and puts a new one.

```js
const generatebutton = document.getElementById("explainbutton");


const wt = document.getElementById("b2");
const ht = document.getElementById("b3");
const bmi = document.getElementById("b5");
const calc = document.getElementById("b7");
const clr = document.getElementById("b8");

// // calculate bmi funtion
function calculate() {
  const wt = document.getElementById("b2").value;
  const ht = document.getElementById("b3").value;
  const solve = Number.parseFloat(wt / ht ** 2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("b5").textContent = solve;
};

// function make explain button appear 

function genbutton() {
  generatebutton.style.visibility = "visible";
};


calc.addEventListener("click", function() {
  calculate();
  genbutton();
});

clr.addEventListener("click", function() {
  wt.value = "";
  ht.value = "";
  bmi.textContent = "";
});


//set variables for explanation
const explain = document.getElementById("explain")

const under = document.getElementById("under")

const healthy = document.getElementById("healthy")

const over = document.getElementById("over")

const obese = document.getElementById("obese")

//pop up text
var text = '';
var btn = document.getElementById("explainbutton");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const bmi = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b5").textContent);
  if (text != ''){
    explain.classList.toggle(text)
  }
  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    text = "open-under"
    
  } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
    text = "open-healthy"
  } else if (bmi > 24.9 && bmi < 29.9) {
    text = "open-over"
  } else {
    text = "open-obese"
    
  }
  explain.classList.toggle(text)
});
```

```css
#explainbutton {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 190px;
}


/* pop-up explanation options */

.box {
  background: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-under .under {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-healthy .healthy {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-over .over {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.open-obese .obese {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


/*  */
```

```html
<div id="b1">
  <span id="sp1">
    WEIGHT(kg) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b2">
  </input>
</div>
<br>
<div id="b9">
  <span id="sp2">
    HEIGHT(m) :
  </span>
  <input type="number" id="b3">
  </input>
</div>
<br>

<div id="bmibox">
  BMI :
  <span id="b5"> </span>
  <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="What does this mean?" class="styled-button-2" id="explainbutton" />
  <div class="box" id="explain">
    <span class="under" id="under">You are in the underweight range</span>
    <span class="healthy" id="healthy"> You are in the healthy range </span>
    <span class="over" id="over"> You are in the overweight range </span>
    <span class="obese" id="obese"> You are in the obese range</span>
  </div>


</div>

<br>
<br>
<div id="b6">
  <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Calculate" class="styled-button-2" id="b7" />
  <button id="b8">Clear</button>
</div>
```